# Infinite auto scroll top-to-bottom and back, how to control/configure speed, time of pause at end?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, infinite, autoscroll

I'm trying to make a long page of images scroll up and down infinitely (for an exhibition).

This is what I've been working with (code I found here, so helpful!):
https://jsfiddle.net/p7r73tke/

It's mostly working ok for what I want, but I need more control over speed and pause.

**How can I make the pause at the top longer?**

**is there a way to make it pause randomly for ~1 second ?**

**does anyone know of an easier way to do what I'm thinking of? maybe as samuel-liew suggests, javascript is not the best solution for the problem**

thank u thank u!

```
function scrollpage() {
function f() {
  window.scrollTo(0, i); //idk
  if (status == 0) {
    i = i + 50; //scroll speed top to bottom?
    if (i >= Height) {
      status = 30; //idk?
    }
  } else {
    i = i - 10; //scroll speed bottom to top?
    if (i <= 1) { // if you don't want continue scroll then remove this if condition 
      status = 0; //idk
    }
  }
  setTimeout(f, 0.01); //idk
}
f();
}
var Height = 15000; //doc height input manually
var i = 1, //idk
j = Height,
status = 0; //idk
scrollpage();
```

(I'm new and tender to JavaScript, as you can see in the comments)

Thanks for any help!

Comment: maybe it has to do with var Height = 1500; being set too long for the example? on the page i'm making it's set to the exact size, but still pauses too long at the bottom, is that possible?

Comment: but if there's any way to make it pause for a moment at the top? that would really help

Answer (score 1):

**jQuery solution:**

```
var speed = 10000; // 10000 = 10 seconds

var doScroll = function() {
  var direction = $(window).scrollTop() != 0 ? 0 : $(document).height() - $(window).height();
  $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: direction }, speed, 'linear');
}

doScroll(); // once on page load
setInterval(doScroll, speed + 10); // once every X ms
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/samliew/k35tbgau/

---

**JavaScript:**

Sorry, I do not recommend pure JavaScript for this as you have to take into account:

1. Cross-browser issues with getting window height, document height, and current scroll position
2. Recalculating the scroll speed based on content height every time the browser is resized
3. Programming an animation function
4. Keeping track of intervals and timeouts, and when you need to clear them
5. Direction/state of scroll
6. Taking into consideration if user manually scrolls the scrollbar

   *Probably lots more...*

Comment: fortunately I don't have to worry about cross-browser issues or things like that as it's only to be viewed offline on one computer hooked up to a large monitor.

Comment: & there's no user interaction with the piece, and it's just for display purposes. I just need to be able to set the speed up and down as appropriate (slow going down, fast going up, like someone browsing a website) then walk away and leave it running/looping